# Storing only the last 500 records for a user in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Howdie,

I'm trying writing a system that makes predictions about its users based on a test. For part of this I only want the database to store the most recent 500 values.

The current fields I am storing are

```
ID (Auto increment)
USERID (the users unique ID)
SCORE(an integer)
```

In an ideal world I would Like the system to drop the oldest row when a unique user gets over 500 records in the database. Is there an easy way to automate this in PHP without making the code really heavy?

Comment: I'm of the "never delete anything" school of thought. Why would you want to delete stuff? _Especially as you're using it for modelling_? All your models will subtly change without you realising and you're going to have to continually re-factor. What happens if, in a years time, you want to keep 1,000 records but can't because you've deleted everything?

Comment: I'd do this in 2 separate steps: (1) Use `limit` in the queries that *consume* this data so they take into account at most 500 records. (2) Run a batch every so often that cleans out extraneous records for everybody, if you really want to. @Ben is probably right: Why delete it? (Limit: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html#id932167)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to store a date/time field so you can determine what's over 1 month old, then it becomes as simple as:

```
DELETE FROM yourtable
WHERE timestampfield > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

If you're not going to have any 'gaps' in the auto_incremented ID, you could do a very simple (and very failure prone):

```
INSERT INTO ....  <--add new record

DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE (id < (INSERT_ID() - 500))
```

but this would be very unreliable.

Comment: Would this cause an issue as the auto_increment id is consistant for every post but the user may change?... eg if Chris had 20 records which he added 20 days ago but sam had 500 that she added today would Chris's records get dropped?.

Is it possible to make the 500 limit user dependent?

Comment: That makes it far more difficult, and I'd suggest you add the timestamp field, and just add a `... AND (userId = 'Chris')` to the delete query.

Comment: I think I'm going to drop the idea of using a month and just focus on the 500 records as some users may go on holiday and not use the system for a month. Though I'm not sure how to count records and isolate the oldest one after you hit the magic 500 :-S

Comment: The oldest records will also have the lowest ID numbers. MySQL doesn't allow this directly, but with workarounds, something like `DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE id NOT IN (select id from yourtable order by id desc limit 500 and userid=...) AND userid=...` would do the trick.

Comment: Interesting... I think that may be the best way to do it... Cheers buddy!